# How do I get HTML rendered in creating email message with velocity?

Tags: html, email, velocity

I use velocity to create a string writer, then merge that into a template.  The template #includes html to make a simple table, yet only the raw HTML shows up in the email... it does not get rendered.  Email is being sent from Google server to outlook client.
Can anyone tell me How can I get rendered HTML into an email message created with Velocity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a `Content-type: text/html` header.

Appart from that, you have to be aware that all the different email clients may strip the HTML tags and features (for example, styles), so you have to experiment with different email clients and try to stick to a very basic feature set.

Comment: Hi, I tried setting Content-type: text/html header. I have tried using javax.mail version 1.5.0-b01 / 1.4.7 /1.4.6 and 1.4. None have worked. I am getting raw html text in mails published instead of html content.

Comment: I no longer have experience with all this. Anyway, I would say check the raw email received in your email client (even Gmail has an option for this). Verify that the `Content-type` header is there, it is not duplicated and that is effectively applied to the content part is being displayed (I mention this in case you're using a multipart to send both plain text and HTML, make sure HTML has the proper header, as they are nested). Hope this points you in the right direction.