# Email receiving as a raw html

Tags: java, html, email, velocity, sendgrid

The email which I am sending through sendgrid SMTPAuthenticator is getting delivered and displayed as raw html. I am using velocity template for message content for email in java.

How should I get proper html format in email instead of raw html?

This is the code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    SMTPAuthenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    String text = messageContent;
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sendFrom));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(sendTo));
    message.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    transport.connect();
    transport.sendMessage(message,
    message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
```

I have also added the mime type in vm file inside head element, below is the sample.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Note : The raw html email is displayed only few time and not all time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411904/how-do-i-get-html-rendered-in-creating-email-message-with-velocity?rq=1 in which unfortunately the asker did not accept the answer

Comment: Please red FAQ.  If you share the code, some one could help faster.  Most likely you are not setting its mime type..

Comment: I have already set the mime type to utf-8 and also have added Content-type: text/html. But still it comes

Comment: @EvanKnowles I have already added Content-type: text/html

Comment: @Jayan: I have added the code, Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should also define your Mime Body parts, and initialize your `text` variable as a `MimeBodyPart()` object. Though I would strongly recommend you build a multipart message that sends both a text/plain part as well as a text/html part. It's a common thing ISPs look for in an email, since email clients that cannot render `html` still exist.

```
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        BodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textPart.setContent(
            "Everything is awesome",
            "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(
            "<p> Everything is awesome! </p>",
            "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        multipart.addBodyPart(textPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
```